# Efficient Percentile Selection With SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a Postgres DB.

I have a small table of groups, and a large table of members, where each group is a collection of members, and members belong only to one group.

Each group should have stored percentile information (0th to 100th, 1 percent increments).

I know I can select many percentiles using many subselect queries as in the below example, but this seems really inefficient for 101 (including the 0th) percentile queries.

```
    UPDATE groups as g
        SET percentile_zero = (
            SELECT percentile_cont(0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.age) from members m where m.fk_group_id = 10),
        percentile_one = (
            SELECT percentile_cont(0.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.age) from members m where m.fk_group_id = 10),
...
```

Is there a faster way to do this without the need for separate similar subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would calculate the values once and join:

```
update groups g
    set
    from (select fk_group_id, 
                 percentile_cont(0.00) within group (order by age) as p_00,
                 percentile_cont(0.01) within group (order by age) as p_01,
                 percentile_cont(0.02) within group (order by age) as p_02,
                 . . .
          from members m
          where fk_group_id = 10
          group by fk_group_id
         ) m
     where m.fk_group_id = g.group_id;
```

You can of course use `group by` in the subquery and assign all groups at the same time.

Comment: Accepted, thanks. If I wanted to query for multiple groups at a time, do you have any further advice? `AND g.group_id in (10,12)` yields only one output row that obtains a percentile across rows, instead of two rows each with their own group percentiles

Comment: @JohnVandivier . . . Just change the `where` clause to whatever you want or remove it for all groups.